# Visual Basic 2010 Crashes When Loading New Project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I recently tried using Visual Basic 2010 Express on my Windows 10 (32-bit) computer when I encountered a problem. When I clicked on "Create New Project", I received this

[image: Error Message]:

I have tried uninstalling then installing. This problem also occurs with Visual Basic 2017!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So have you got Just-In-Time debugging enabled, which is what the error message is saying?

Comment: Wait a minute - why are you using VS**2010** in 2017?

Comment: @stuart I tried using VS2017 but same problem occurred so I tried an earlier version

Comment: Also, How do I disable Just-In-Time debugging?

Comment: @stuartd : I use VS2010, but that's because I think VS2012-2015's designs are ugly. ;)